# What is the auto Bracketed List Syntax?

Tags: c++, c++17, auto, decomposition

[W.F.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4324224/w-f) gave a now-deleted answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41556257/2642059) which used the line:

```
auto [x, y] = div_t{ 1, 0 };
```

From the code in the answer it looks like that's like a `tie` for the `div_t` struct. I was hoping that someone could explain what was going on here. The complete function code was as follows:

```
constexpr bool first_quot() {
    auto [x, y] = std::div_t{1, 0};
    (void)y;
    return x;
}
```

Comment: That is called [*structured bindings*](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0217r2.html). And yes it works similar to `tie` (but with automatic declaration, definition and initialization all in one go).

Comment: I realized that the answer of hvd actually covered fully your question :) As for the syntax it is [structured binding](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0144r0.pdf)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude not entirely as `tie` as it is actually declaration of variables `x` and `y` and `std::tie` binds references of already existing variables and I'm not sure if `tie` can bind these variables to structure - as far as I know it can only tie these variables to `std::tuple` elements. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @W.F. Updated my comment. And your right about `std::tie` only being able to handle `std::tuple` (or `std::pair`, because that's what the assignment operator of `std::tuple` handles and `std::tie` returns a `std::tuple`).

Comment: Oh one more thing ;) actually my answer was wrong with using structure binding... my answer should more look like `constexpr bool first_quot() { return std::div_t{1, 0}.quot; }` (so no c++17 even needed) to work according to my intention :) But as it is deleted anyway I haven't edited it :)

Comment: @W.F. The reason that I was excited by your answer, was that I understood it to use a `constexpr` if so I could actually use that to select the `generate` statement that I executed allowing me to use the curly brace initialization that I was trying to in the first place.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Any chance I could convince you to source that information and type it up as an answer? When I look up [`auto`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) I don't see that as a potential syntax. I'd sure like the opportunity to read up and understand what's going on here.

Comment: I *have* seen it on cppreference, but can't seem to find it now. :/

Comment: @JonathanMee I'm glad it was helpful :)

Comment: Now when I know the actual terms in the specification, I find references *everywhere*, including [on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/declarations#Decomposition_declaration)... :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yeah: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/declarations#Decomposition_declaration

Comment: @W.F. So what's the point of the `(void)y` is that just to prevent unused variable warnings?

Comment: @JonathanMee exactly. Unfortunetly I don't think that you can use structure binding (or however it is called now) with unnamed variable...

Comment: @W.F. I found a way to write a C++11 helper function without direct member assignment! Check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41592619/2642059 I'm pretty excited, except for the fact that it doesn't work on Visual Studio :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the most [most recent draft of the C++17 specification](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/n4618.pdf) it's called "Decomposition declarations" and is defined in section 8.5 [dcl.decomp].