# Unpack to function parameters

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, structured-bindings

Is it theoretically possible to add a language feature to unpack structures into the function actual parameter lists? I mean the following.

```
template< typename ...Ts >
void f(Ts... values) { (std::cout << ... << values) << std::endl; }

struct S { int a; char c; double d; };
S s{1, '2', 3.0};
f([s]);

void g(int, int, int) {}

g([s]); // warning about narrowing conversion

void h(int &, int &, int &) {}

h([s]); // hard error ("cannot bind to...")
```

It would be handy to deal with suitable structures of unknown count of members. Because current *structured bindings* can't "unpack" structures of unknown number of components (like `auto... [x] = s;`) due to lack of the template context, where only possible `operator ...` to deal with variadic number of types/values.

What downsides can be on this way?

Comment: `f` aside, you could use https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get, turn it into a `std::tuple`, and use `std::apply`.

Comment: @chris I am familiar with the technique, but there is too much boilerplate code to deal with reasonable numbers of components in generic code if I want e.g. to [get a n-th `struct` field](https://gist.github.com/tomilov/0cf10f110a8e1a0b486603bba500640a). I am awared about workarounds.

Comment: The reason there's hacky boilerplate is that there's no directly supported way to do this. The technique piggybacks on a feature of the language designed for a different problem. But the boilerplate shouldn't be a big deal if using a library instead of copying/adapting code into your project. And honestly, I would find a structure with more members than is supported (appears to be 100) to be pretty insane.

Comment: Side note - this feature isn't actually called *structured binding* but *decomposition declaration*. see e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41570596/4324224)

Comment: @Orient: You think too small. [This](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/p0535r0.html) is a far better idea.

Comment: @NicolBolas Sure =). It is just a first thought. But huge syntactic innovations are hardly possible to be accepted by the Committee.

Comment: @Orient: "*But huge syntactic innovations are hardly possible to be accepted by the Committee.*" Nothing gets accepted by the committee from a Stack Overflow question. The committee only responds to *papers* that are submitted and presented, which that one is. So despite being a "huge syntactic innovation", it's far more likely that the paper gets accepted than your post here.

Comment: @NicolBolas It is obvious. My question is not a proposal.

Comment: @Orient: Your question is also *pointless*. Could you add such a language feature? Sure; in the sense that you could write a proposal, present it to the committee, and get them to agree with it. So I don't see what the point of asking about it on SO is.

Comment: @NicolBolas can you help me to find a proper place to ask such a questions?

Comment: @Orient: I could suggest the [ISO C++ Future Proposals forum](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!forum/std-proposals), but the paper I linked to was heavily discussed there, and yours would be deemed a pale imitation. Which... it is. Also, if you're going to bring it up on that form anyway, I would advise you to put more thought into it than you've shown in this question. You should have some idea as to what `[s]` means exactly. You should know how `[s]` behaves, whether or not other arguments are allowed along side it. And so forth.

Comment: @NicolBolas Don't worry about my inner world =). I can handle. But current proposal (atm implemented in *clang++* and *g++*) is even more poor in a way then linked proposal. I see contradiction in what you said with real world.

Comment: @Orient: Um... what "current proposal" are you talking about? The one I linked to isn't available in any compiler. And the one you're talking about doesn't exist. At least, not that I'm aware of.

Comment: @NicolBolas I am talking about [*structured bindings*](http://wg21.link/p0217r3) of course.