# Why Won't Visual Studio let me use a Templatized, constexpr Function in enable_if?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, visual-studio-2015, constexpr

So I've boiled this down to the minimal, complete, verifiable example and it seems that Visual Studio 2015 just won't allow me to use a templatized, `constexpr` function in an `enable_if`.

For example:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr bool condition() { return sizeof(T) > 1; }
```

Gives me the error:

> error C2995: `enable_if<_Test,T>::type test(void)`: function template has already been defined

When I try to use it in substitution failure is not an error compilation like this:

```
template <typename T>
enable_if_t<condition<T>()> test() { cout << "true\n"; }

template <typename T>
enable_if_t<!condition<T>()> test() { cout << "false\n"; }
```

This works fine in gcc: http://ideone.com/m9LDdS

And it works fine in Visual Studio 2015 if I remove the templatization of `condition`. I believe that `constexpr` functions were introduced in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), why isn't Visual Studio 2015 supporting this? Is it a bug?

Comment: `constexpr` functions were in fact introduced in C++11.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx They don't support extended constexpr FWIW.

Comment: VS doesn't have complete Expression SFINAE support yet

Comment: @KerrekSB Thanks I've updated. That just puts Visual Studio 2015 3 more years out of date.

Comment: Try `template <class T,class=enable_if_t<condition<T>()>>
void test() { cout << "true\n"; }`?

Comment: @GillBates Is this "extended `constexpr`" functionality? As has been pointed out this should have worked since C++11.

Comment: @bolov I'm not sure what that means but it seems like it might be the problem.

Comment: @JonathanMee The main flaw in MSVC's SFINAE is not extended `constexpr`, but what they call "expression SFINAE".  The biggest part that it means is that `decltype` doesn't really work with SFINAE, but what exactly it covers is not something I've ever been able to work out.  Maybe it is causing a problem here.  But the error message makes me think that it is seeing two templates it somehow considers identical, which may be an unrelated problem.  Each version of MSVC states they have solved some "expression SFINAE" problems.  :/

Comment: @Yakk That didn't work for me either, still gives error C2995. You can test for yourself here: http://rextester.com/QMEU55701

Comment: @JonathanMee it simply means that other than very simple expressions for SFINAE you can't be sure SFINAE will work on VS.

Comment: @JonathanMee The solution suggested by `Yakk` works: http://rextester.com/XLEV56307

Comment: @SimonKraemer Actually it doesn't: http://rextester.com/live/OFNM72056 But strangely when you add in the `enable_if` on the first `test`'s return it does work o.O

Comment: @JonathanMee .... Oh I missed that.

Comment: @SimonKraemer That just makes me more confused at what's going on here.

Comment: @bolov Well... this MCVE is very simple compared to [what I'm actually trying to do](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41592619/2642059). Does that count?

Comment: @JonathanMee I can offer you a workaround by using a template struct as proxy. http://rextester.com/TGMB94634

Comment: @JonathanMee yes, it means that your real example has even less chance to work on VS. Take it as it is: VS doesn't yet have support this feature. They are working on it, as Yakk said, they incrementally added support with each version. You have a few options: a) wait until they implement it in a future version, b) switch to a different compiler (this might not be a solution) c) search for a workaround (you should focus on finding a workaround)

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/06/07/expression-sfinae-improvements-in-vs-2015-update-3/

Comment: @JonathanMee The workaround applied to your example: http://rextester.com/ULDFM22040

Comment: @SimonKraemer Yup, I was just reading through all the bugs... Yikes. If you care to post as an answer I will accept shortly.

Comment: @T.C. Thanks that had the workaround for me, albeit a somewhat ugly one.

Comment: @GillBates It looks like they have partial support for extended constexpr, but they're not all the way there yet.  [This](http://ideone.com/sCPYi0) works on [the online MSVC compiler](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/), but I believe Community edition still has trouble with it (not 100% sure of this, though).

Comment: @JustinTime Hmmm... I am using the community version... Though my current problem certainly extends to all versions. I thought that the compiler was consistent across all the versions anyway?

Comment: @JonathanMee I believe all of the installable versions use the same compiler, but I'm not sure if the online compiler does, too; the online one at cloudapp has a different build number than the VS 2015 Update 3 one (19.10.24903.0 for Cloudapp, 14.0.25420.10 for Update 3), but I'm not sure if that indicates anything more than that it's an online build.  I _think_ the online one is updated more frequently than major updates are pushed to the installable versions (especially considering it was updated a bit less than a week ago), but that's honestly just a guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem seems to be that MSVC14/VS2015 is not capable of correctly resolving SFINAE expressions in combination with return values of constexpr functions as template parameters.

As a workaround you can assign the return value of your constexpr to a 'static const' member of a struct and use this member as template parameter.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

using std::enable_if_t;
using std::cout;

template <typename T>
constexpr bool condition() { return sizeof(T) > 1; }

template <typename T>
struct condition_ { static const bool value = condition<T>();};

template <typename T>
enable_if_t<condition_<T>::value> test() { cout << "true\n"; }
template <typename T>
enable_if_t<!condition_<T>::value> test() { cout << "false\n"; }

int main() {
    test<int>();
    test<bool>();
    return 0;
}
```

http://rextester.com/VVNHB62598

---

You also mentioned in the comments that your actual problem appeared in another case than your MCVE ([How can I Initialize a div_t Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41556257/how-can-i-initialize-a-div-t-object/41592619#41592619))

For this case the workaround might look like this:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <utility>


template <typename T>
using divtype = decltype(std::div(std::declval<T>(), std::declval<T>()));


template <typename T>
struct condition
{
    static const bool value = divtype<T>{ 1, 0 }.quot != 0;
};


template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<condition<T>::value, divtype<T>> make_div(const T quot, const T rem) { return{ quot, rem }; }

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<!condition<T>::value, divtype<T>> make_div(const T quot, const T rem) { return{ rem, quot }; }

int main() {

    make_div<int>(1, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

http://rextester.com/ULDFM22040

---

According to this [Visual Studio C++ Team blog entry](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/06/19/c111417-features-in-vs-2015-rtm/) VS2015 does not have (complete) support for [Expression SFINAE](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2634.html) yet.

> [1] We’re planning to start implementing Expression SFINAE in the compiler immediately after 2015 RTM, and we’re planning to deliver it in an Update to 2015, supported for production use.  (But not necessarily 2015 Update 1.  It might take longer.)

Comment: Just as a comment to my answer: In most cases you won't even need the constexpr function and can go with the struct only. In the example above you could easily replace `static const bool value = condition<T>();` with `static const bool value = sizeof(T) > 1;` and get rid of the constexpr function. I would say that it depends on the use case and personal preference which way to here.

Comment: I would never, ever trust a MSVC SFINAE case where there is `decltype` as part of the decision to fail or not; I've seen far to many bugs, where it "cache"s the wrong result and gets completely insane behavior.  Maybe your "go through a template type" solution avoids this, but I'd want to see extensive testing before I trusted it.  The "incomplete support" basically means "it goes wrong in unpredictable ways rather than failing with an error".  It is horrid.

Comment: @Yakk Good to know. In this case `divtype` should rather provide 3 specializations for the 3 overloads of `std::div`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you end up with two different template `test` of the form:

```
template<class>void test()
```

and the compiler complains.  This may be related to expression SFINAE failure, where it doesn't evaluate the expression of `condition<T>()` "early enough", or fails in another way.

Here is a workaround:

```
template<std::size_t>
struct counter{ enum type{}; };

template<std::size_t N>
using counter_type=typename counter<N>::type;

template <typename T>
constexpr bool condition() { return sizeof(T) > 1; }

template <class T,counter_type<0>...,class=std::enable_if_t<condition<T>()>>
void test() { std::cout << "true\n"; }

template <class T,counter_type<1>...,class=std::enable_if_t<!condition<T>()>>
void test() { std::cout << "false\n"; }
```

Now the template signatures of the two different `test` differ, and the expression SFINAE evaluation of `condition<T>()` not working quite right doesn't cause a problem.

Comment: Can you help me understand what `counter_type` is doing in the template parameters? It seems completely unrelated to the other template arguments. Maybe that's the point?

Comment: @JonathanMee Guarantees they have different template signatures

Comment: As far as I understand it: `counter_type<0>` is different from `counter_type<1>` making the two template functions "really" different from another. As it is variadic (see the ellipsis) you don't have to pass anything at this position. It just helps the compiler to distinguish between the 2 functions.

Comment: @SimonKraemer Yeah that's what I got too. Seems like a pretty high hoop to jump through when the SFINAE should already work :(

Answer (score 2):

Another option to @Yakk's answer:

```
template <class T, std::enable_if_t<(sizeof(T) > 1)>* = nullptr>
void test() { std::cout << "true\n"; }

template <class T, std::enable_if_t<!(sizeof(T) > 1)>* = nullptr>
void test() { std::cout << "false\n"; }
```

EDIT: just saw that this is basically the solution to which TC pointed to in the comments.

EDIT2: corrected code to compile in MSVC2015, see comments.

Comment: Can you help me understand this? So if the `enable_if` succeeds we're compiling `template <class T, void* = nullptr> void test() { cout << "true\n"; }` that assignment in the template parameters doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @JonathanMee: see  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36499008/sfinae-works-differently-in-cases-of-type-and-non-type-template-parameters). Funnily, it's also Yakk who gave the answer :-)

Comment: Does this really work? Rextester doesn't like it: http://rextester.com/ZCLIE12472

Comment: @SimonKraemer: thanks for the comment. [coliru does](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d2099231fad37aa) (and it also did before C++11 afai remember), moreover it's a basic trick ... not sure why rextester doesn't.

Comment: @Yakk: seems so. (anyways I think I remember it worked for me in MSVC2015, but maybe I'm wrong)

Comment: Tried it locally and it doesn't work here either. Same error.

Comment: Sorry, my memory was refering to a slightly different case, namely where `condition()` is directly replaced by the condition itself, i.e. here `(sizeof(T)>1)`. Then it works in MSVC 2015. Otherwise, Simon's answer applies.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known MSVC issue, and was mentioned in one of their blog posts.  What's going on is that the compiler can't recognise that SFINAE makes the second version of `test()` different than the first, and it needs a little hint; a simple dummy parameter will suffice, allowing it to differentiate the two versions.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
using std::enable_if_t; using std::cout;

template <typename T>
constexpr bool condition() { return sizeof(T) > 1; }

#ifdef    _MSC_VER
    #define MSVC_DUMMY int /*msvc_dummy*/ = 0
#else  // _MSC_VER
    #define MSVC_DUMMY
#endif // _MSC_VER

template <typename T>
enable_if_t<condition<T>()> test() { cout << "true\n"; }

template <typename T>
enable_if_t<!condition<T>()> test(MSVC_DUMMY) { cout << "false\n"; }

int main() {
    test<char>();
    test<int>();
}
```

This [works on MSVC](http://rextester.com/UENF27655), with only minimal modifications to the code.  It's also easy to remove once they eventually get it working without the hint.

---

If a consistent interface is desired, this can be hidden behind a helper function.

```
template <typename T>
enable_if_t<condition<T>()> test_() { cout << "true\n"; }

template <typename T>
enable_if_t<!condition<T>()> test_(MSVC_DUMMY) { cout << "false\n"; }

template <typename T>
auto test() { return test_<T>(); }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't remember exactly which blog post it was mentioned in, so I can't provide a link.