# What is Allowed in a constexpr Function?

Tags: c++, function, c++14, constexpr, c++17

[`constexpr` functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) are not supposed to contain:

> A definition of a variable of non-literal type

But in this answer a lambda is defined in one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41616651/2642059

```
template <typename T>
constexpr auto make_div(const T quot, const T rem)
{
    return [&]() {
        decltype(std::div(quot, rem)) result;
        result.quot = quot;
        result.rem = rem;
        return result;
    }();
}
```

and in my comment I define a `div_t` in one: [How can I Initialize a div_t Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41556257/how-can-i-initialize-a-div-t-object/41616651?noredirect=1#comment70436998_41616651)

```
template <typename T>
constexpr decltype(div(T{}, T{})) make_div(const T quot, const T rem)
{
    decltype(div(T{}, T{})) x{};
    x.quot = quot;
    x.rem = rem;
    return x;
}
```

Exactly what is meant by the prohibition of the "definition of a variable of non-literal type"?

Visual Studio 2015 won't allow my definition of a `div_t` but I find it nonsensical that it would be allowable to just wrap such illegitimate behavior in a lambda and execute it. I'd like to know which if either of the compilers are behaving correctly with respect to the `div_t` definition.

Comment: What version of the C++ language? The requirements were relaxed quite a bit from 2011.

Comment: @rubenvb Good question, I've edited. But C++14.

Comment: A lambda expression is a expression, not a variable definition. But until C++17, a lambda expression cannot appear in a [constant expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression). Indeed, [when the context requires a constant expression, MSVC will complain](http://rextester.com/ZBRLBR12534).

Comment: @cpplearner So my (the first) example only compiles as the constexpr function is evaluated as const function? In my opinion the second example  should not compile by definition.

Comment: @cpplearner Incidentally if you don't try to assign the result of `make_div` to a `constexpr` variable your Visual Studio compiler error goes away. Perhaps `make_div` really isn't `constexpr` and the compiler's letting us get away with it?

Comment: I don't think VS2015 supports C++14 extended `constexpr`. That explains your second function template since in C++11 `constexpr` functions are basically limited to a single return statement; it has nothing to do with "non-literal type" (and `div_t` is a literal type). The first one is ill-formed NDR pre-C++17.

Comment: @T.C. Sounds like a workable answer to me if you can support that Visual Studio 2015 doesn't support C++14 `constexpr` functions.

Comment: @rubenvb I've gone ahead and posted an answer that addresses, C++11, C++14, and C++17, so I've deleted the requirement the question.

Comment: @JonathanMee That's great. I thought someone might want to do this five minutes after posting my pesky comment...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's virtually guaranteed that if there's a discrepancy gcc has the correct behavior, because Visual Studio 2015 doesn't support [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14)'s extension of `constexpr`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx#C-14-Core-Language-Features

## C++11 `constexpr` functions

The function body can *only* contain:

> - null statements (plain semicolons)
> - `static_assert` declarations
> - `typedef` declarations and alias declarations that do not define classes or enumerations
> - `using` declarations
> - `using` directives
> - exactly one `return` statement

So [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) cannot tolerate the definition of `decltype(div(T{}, T{})) x{}`. It would however be acceptable to roll the ternary suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41592619/2642059) in a `constexpr` function to achieve the same results:

```cpp
template <typename T>
constexpr auto make_div(const T quot, const T rem)
{
    using foo = decltype(div(T{}, T{}));
                         
    return foo{1, 0}.quot != 0 ? foo{quot, rem} : foo{rem, quot};
}
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://rextester.com/OHIUF61182)

## C++14 `constexpr` functions

The function body may contain *anything but*:

> - an asm declaration
> - a goto statement
> - a statement with a label other than case and default
> - a try-block
> - a definition of a variable of non-literal type
> - a definition of a variable of static or thread storage duration
> - a definition of a variable for which no initialization is performed

Where a "Literal Type" is defined [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/LiteralType), specifically for objects though, they may be aggregate types with a trivial destructor. So `div_t` definitely qualifies. Thus [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14), and by extension gcc, can tolerate the definition of `decltype(div(T{}, T{})) x{}`.

## C++17 `constexpr` functions

C++17 added support for closure types to the definition of "Literal Type", so I find it strange that both gcc and Visual Studio support the use of the lambda in the `return` statement. I guess that's either forward looking support or the compiler chose to inline the lambda. In either case I don't think that it qualifies as a [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) `constexpr` function.

[[Source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr)]

Comment: @jnoathan_mee "The function body may contain anything but: ..." , we cannot call non-constexpr function in the body, right?

Comment: @camino Correct, the result of this function must be calculable at compile-time, thus functions or parameters which cannot satisfy this requirement are not acceptable. That point isn't clearly documented though is it :(