# constexpr function taking const char*

Tags: c++, constexpr

Im compiling using MSVC v141 with `/std:c++17`.

```
constexpr const char* test(const char* foo) {
    return foo + 1;
}

constexpr const char* bc = test("abc");
```

compiles just fine, whereas

```
constexpr const char* test(const char* foo) {
    constexpr auto bar = foo;
    return bar + 1;
}

constexpr const char* bc = test("abc");
```

Fails with:

> error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
>
> failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime
>
> note: see usage of 'foo'

Is this correct behaviour or a bug in MSVC?

Comment: I am trying to find if it is allowed to declare variables in a constexpr function. There are some limitations there.

Comment: Found the limitations listed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41618576/what-is-allowed-in-a-constexpr-function,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like expected behavior to me. A function declared with `constexpr` means that it can be evaluated at compile time but not that it is required to be. So your function should also be valid when evaluated at runtime. This is the problem line

```
constexpr auto bar = foo;
```

because it attempts to create a `constexpr` object from a non-`constexpr` one.