# What is Allowed in a consteval Function?

Tags: c++, function, c++20, constexpr, consteval

(See for reference [What is Allowed in a constexpr Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41618576/what-is-allowed-in-a-constexpr-function))

I know that `constexpr` functions have some restrictions upon what is allowed in them. The following is a quote lists them.

> The function body may contain anything but:
>
> - an asm declaration
> - a goto statement
> - a statement with a label other than case and default
> - a try-block
> - a definition of a variable of non-literal type
> - a definition of a variable of static or thread storage duration
> - a definition of a variable for which no initialization is performed

I'd like to know, how does the restrictions upon `consteval` function differ from the one specified above. Is there something that can be allowed in `consteval` fucntion but not `constexpr` function, and vise versa.

Comment: The restrictions you mention apply to constant expressions, which are more general than `constexpr` functions.

Comment: I believe try-blocks are okay in C++20 and beyond. You just may not actually `throw` anything. Makes it easier to write code for either evaluation mode. `throw`'s just translate to compile time errors during compile time evaluation.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica can you elaborate upon not being allowed to `throw` anything? How does it translate to compile time error?

Comment: Simple. The compiler stops constant evaluation, points at the throw expression it reached and says "error". So long as it doesn't reach it, no harm.

Answer (score 1):

Just like `constexpr`, `consteval` makes a function be a **constexpr function**.  The list of requirements (which shrank significantly in C++20 from that C++14 version) applies to that broader category.  It’s **calls** to immediate (*i.e.*, `consteval`) functions that are further restricted.

Comment: Can you elaborate upon the list of requirements in C++20?

Comment: @KarenBaghdasaryan: It’s down to `goto`/labels and definitions of non-automatic or non-literal variables, and even those should be gone in C++23 (leaving only the parameter/return types, base classes, and invocability).