# Can any reentrant function in C++ be refactored into a constexpr function?

Tags: c++, multithreading, constexpr-function

***Edit at 10/10/2023 06:30 UTC:***

Thanks to valuable comments from @DrewDormann, @Solomon Slow, @Pepijn Kramer, and @user17732522, I've come to realize that I posed a question without thorough consideration. Allow me to provide further clarification.

For a reentrant function, its result *seems* can be determined only by its arguments. If so, if its arguments are constant, it becomes possible to determine the result at compile-time. That is why I have the question about the relationship between reentrant and `constexpr` functions.

However, I made an mistake in my assumption concerning "constant arguments." While it's true that non-type template parameters are constant, it's important to note that constant arguments do not necessarily have to be template arguments.

Regarding the parameter type of std::string, we have examples of constexpr functions like the following in the latest C++ standard:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

constexpr string say_hello(string x) { return "Hello, "s + x; }

int main()
{
    cout << say_hello("World") << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

So, **can any reentrant function in C++ be refactored into a `constexpr` function?**

And thanks for the comments and answers to the original question.

---

***Original Question***

**Can any reentrant function in C++ be refactored into a constexpr function template?**

I learned that a function (in C) is considered reentrant when it adheres to the following rules:

- Do not use static or global variables in your function since those may be changed by time your function resumes
- Function must not modify its own code (e.g. some low level graphic routines may have "habit" to generate itself)
- Do not call any function that does not comply with the two rules above

In C++, similar principles may apply. Then I noticed that the rules about `constexpr` functions is similar too.

For a reentrant function like:

```
float f(float x) { return x*x; }
```

It can be refactored into a `constexpr` function template in C++20:

```
template <float X> constexpr float f() { return X*X; }
```

It is a simple example. For more complex situation, however, is such a refactoring always possible? In other words, Can any reentrant function in C++ be refactored into a `constexpr` function template?

Comment: It depends on the C++ standard used.  [What is Allowed in a constexpr Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41618576/what-is-allowed-in-a-constexpr-function)

Comment: constexpr functions have their own rules (as @DrewDormann linked to). Also you do not need function templates for constexpr functions they are not directly related. `constexpr f(float x) { return x*x; }` is a valid constexpr function too. And you can use it like this : `static constexpr auto my_constant = f(2.0f);`

Comment: The answer is trivially no, already because not all types that can be function parameters can be non-type template parameters. E.g. `std::string f(std::string x) { return x; }` is reentrant by your definition, but `template<std::string x>` is not permitted because `std::string` is not a structural type. But I suppose this is conceptionally not what you have in mind? What exactly is it that you want to have verified?

Answer (score 0):

**No**: you can build tons of functions that will be completely re-entrant, but cannot be refactored into constexpr functions.

There are a ton of API's with re-entrant functions in the world, requiring just 1 of them will stop you from refactoring it as a constexpr.

On a purely theoretical level: **maybe**: might require re-implementing a whole lot of code.